# How to draw a line from mouse to a point in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_center = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_center = round(((event.y() - 250)**2 + (event.x() - 500)**2)**0.5)
        self.label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "Distance from center: " + str(distance_from_center))       

        q = QPainter()  #Painting the line
        q.begin(self)
        q.drawLine(event.x(), event.y(), 250, 500)
        q.end()

    def drawPoints(self, qp, x, y):
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPoint(x, y)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I'm trying to do is paint a simple line from the position of the mouse to the middle of the widget using this:

```
        q = QPainter()  #Painting the line
        q.begin(self)
        q.drawLine(event.x(), event.y(), 250, 500)
        q.end()
```

But when I run it, no line is visible. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement the function `QPaintEvent`, in this function you must draw the line, in addition you must call the function `update()` to update the drawing.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_center = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()
        self.pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_center = round(((event.y() - 250)**2 + (event.x() - 500)**2)**0.5)
        self.label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "Distance from center: " + str(distance_from_center))       
        self.pos = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.pos:
            q = QPainter(self)
            q.drawLine(self.pos.x(), self.pos.y(), 500, 250)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It crashes when I try to do this, any ideas?

Comment: Moving position variable to outside the methods, next to distance_from_center makes it work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a `QPainter` inside the `paintEvent` method. So one way to fix is to record the x and y coordinates inside the class and update the root widget. This then calls `paintEvent` and you will see the line.

example

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_center = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = -1
        self.y = -1

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        if not (self.x == -1 or self.y == -1):
            q = QPainter()  #Painting the line

            q.begin(self)

            q.drawLine(self.x, self.y, 250, 500)
            q.end()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_center = round(((event.y() - 250)**2 + (event.x() - 500)**2)**0.5)
        self.label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "Distance from center: " + str(distance_from_center))

        self.x = event.x()
        self.y = event.y()

        self.update()

    def drawPoints(self, qp, x, y):
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPoint(x, y)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I wasn't sure about how `self.x` and `self.y` would be set initially. The -1 and the check in the `paintEvent` feels a bit hacky, but at least it paints.

Comment: It crashes whenever I define paintEvent, even if I copy your code exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get any crashes. Seems you got it resolved anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the previous answer, I tried it under Python3.7 and PyQt5. The result was program crash
'Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)'.
And in the comments, there were someone else also mentioned the crash.
I find the solution to this crash:
self.x and self.y must be initialized before the calling of self.show()
So I simply modified the code to as follows:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
    self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
    self.label = QLabel(self)
    self.label.resize(500, 40)
    self.x = 100
    self.y = 100
    self.show()
```